# Get last x commits from Github repo using Github Api V4

Tags: github, graphql, github-api

I'm trying to use the new Github GraphQL api (v4) and I don't seem to be able to figure out how to get the last x commits for **master**. I've used **repository** and **ref** but they still don't give me what I need.

The query below almost gives me what I need:

```graphql
query{
  repository(owner: "typelevel", name: "cats") {
    refs(refPrefix:"refs/heads/", last: 5) {
      edges{
        node {
          associatedPullRequests(states: MERGED, last: 5) {
            edges{
              node {
                title
                baseRef {
                  name
                  prefix
                }
                baseRefName
                commits(last: 10) {
                  edges {
                    node {
                      commit {
                        abbreviatedOid
                        message
                        
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

but:

1. doesn't seems to exactly match what is in the repo
2. limited to PRs
3. seems too unwieldy

I also tried using **defaultBranchRef** but that didn't work either:

```graphql
query{
  repository(owner: "typelevel", name: "cats") {
    defaultBranchRef {
      name
      prefix
      associatedPullRequests(states: [MERGED], last: 5) {
        edges {
          node {
            title
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I've been testing the queries using the [explorer app](https://developer.github.com/v4/explorer/) on the Github api page.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I was able to get this working with:

```graphql
query {
  repository(owner: "typelevel", name: "cats") {
    ref(qualifiedName: "master") {
      target {
        ... on Commit {
          history(first: 10) {
            pageInfo {
              hasNextPage
              endCursor
            }
            edges {
              node {
                oid
                messageHeadline
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

by modifying [this](https://platform.github.community/t/getting-commits-parents/1965) query linked to on the [Github Platform Community](https://platform.github.community/).

Comment: Good catch, probably easier than passing an id. +1

Comment: both of the links went 404 now.

Comment: @LukAron Such is the internet I guess. The Github Platform Community should be somewhere within: https://github.community/ I think. I tried searching for the previous post there but couldn't find anything close to it.

Answer (score 2):

Would using `history` be better in this case?

See [this thread](https://platform.github.community/t/how-to-fetch-commits-from-repos/643/2)

> A "`ref`" (short for reference) is anything that points to a git commit. This could be a local branch, a tag, a remote branch, etc. So `master`, for example, would be considered a ref.
>
> In that vein, you can use the `ref` field on the `Repository` type to get a reference that targets a commit.
> From that commit, you can get all of the commit's parents. If you target `master`, you can get the main `history` of the git repository.

```graphql
query {
  node(id: "MDEwOlJlcG9zaXRvcnk4NDM5MTQ3") {
    ... on Repository {
      ref(qualifiedName: "master") {
        target {
          ... on Commit {
            id
            history(first: 30) {
              totalCount
              pageInfo {
                hasNextPage
              }

              edges {
                node {
                  oid
                  message
                  author {
                    name
                    email
                    date
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Interesting syntax! I didn't know you could do that. I'm not sure how to get the node Id for master in this case?

Comment: @ssanj many object has an ID , https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/graphql/reference/interfaces#node,  any object that implement node interface will have the ID,   to find the ID of your object, you have to find it first,  other than ID, you could use some key to find them, for example , to find a repository, you can do a query with starting point  repository(owner: "typelevel", name: "cats"){ id } in this way you get the ID

Answer (score 0):

Here's the shortest way that works on any default branch even if it's not named `master`

### Last 10 commits

```graphql
{
  repository(owner: "fregante", name: "webext-fun") {
    defaultBranchRef {
      target {
        ... on Commit {
          history(first: 10) {
            nodes {
              oid
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

### Last 1 commit (HEAD)

```graphql
{
  repository(owner: "fregante", name: "webext-fun") {
    defaultBranchRef {
      target {
        oid
      }
    }
  }
}
```